# Why href image does not shown on firefox?

Tags: image, href

i have the below code which is working in all browsers except mozilla which shows only the alt of the image... Whats wrong?

`<a href="mmm.html" >
       <img src="img\rounded\m1.png" alt="m1" width= "10%" height= "30%"/>
</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Wrong characters. Try:

```
 <a href="mmm.html" > 
 <img src="img/rounded/m1.png" alt="m1" width= "10%" height= "30%"/> </a>
```

Pay attention to the path of src. You should use "/" instead of "\".